# Why does my computer try to shut down when I plug in headphones?

Tags: 14.04, power-management, shutdown, headphones

Using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Noticed that when I plug in headphones, a menu appears asking if I want to "lock, suspend, restart, or shut down." Is this normal? How do I fix this if it isn't normal?

Comment: No it's not normal. Answered? ;)

Comment: Haha thank you! I suppose I should have added the follow up of "if not, then how do I fix it?". Also apologies because I am novice AF

Comment: Now it's a question :) upvoted

Comment: Might be a bug.   I'd suggest [submitting a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).  If there's possibility of a prank from coworker or your friend, then check this: there's also a  `/etc/udev/rules.d/  ` folder, where typically people place scripts for specific actions when a device appears or disappears, like opening specific file on USB jump-drive when it is plugged in

Comment: Checked that file and didn't find anything weird.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /etc/acpi`